# ffmpeg convert to h264 Decoder (codec av1) not found for input stream #0:0

Tags: ffmpeg

convert a mp4 file to h264 format by this command below

```
 ffmpeg -i agrawsnzefjkuvsqczucbajyhrpaizzaobubqikayxrbfgfep.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac test.mp4
```

but I get Decoder (codec av1) not found for input stream #0:0

The result of the detail is below:

```
#ffmpeg -i agrawsnzefjkuvsqczucbajyhrpaizzaobubqikayxrbfgfep.mp4 -c:v libx264 -c:a aac test.mp4
ffmpeg version 3.4.8-0ubuntu0.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=0ubuntu0.2 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-librsvg --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxml2 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libdrm --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'agrawsnzefjkuvsqczucbajyhrpaizzaobubqikayxrbfgfep.mp4':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2mp41
    encoder         : Lavf57.83.100
  Duration: 00:04:05.95, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 684 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: av1 (av01 / 0x31307661), none, 1920x1080, 551 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 127 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
File 'test.mp4' already exists. Overwrite ? [y/N] y
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (? (?) -> h264 (libx264))
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (aac (native) -> aac (native))
Decoder (codec av1) not found for input stream #0:0
```

How to fix "Decoder (codec av1) not found for input stream #0:0" error?

Comment: you need a ffmpeg version compiled with libaom. See also: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/AV1

Answer (score 2):

There is no native (software) decoder for AV1 in FFmpeg as of v4.4. However, multiple external decoder libraries are supported via wrappers. These libs are `libaom`, `libdav1d` and various hardware-accelerated decoders such as `nvdec`. You'll need recent ffmpeg (4.3+) to avail many of these. Your ffmpeg ver is 3.4.8. Get a static binary for linux from https://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/

Comment: after I install ffmpeg 4 , already fix this issue