# FFMPEG not working from python subprocess but works from terminal

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess, youtube-dl

I am trying to download a portion of a long youtube video using youtube-dl and ffmpeg. My commands work from the terminal and downloaded video is just as expected but when I am trying to do the same from the python subprocess, I get the following error:

```
Decoder (codec av1) not found for input stream #0:0
```

My terminal commands:

To get video and audio URLs:

```
youtube-dl --youtube-skip-dash-manifest -g "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rQRiS8l30xE&t=627s"
```

It give two URLs, video and audio. I used those urls in FFmpeg -i and it works fine:

```
ffmpeg -ss 12:15 -i "1st-URL" -ss 12:15 -i "2nd-URL" -t 5:15 -map 0:v -map 1:a -c:v libx264 -c:a aac output.mkv
```

But when I am plugging these arguments in a subprocess call it gives me the decoder not found error. I have called the subprocess as below

```
link = subprocess.check_output(["youtube-dl", "--get-url", "--youtube-skip-dash-manifest", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v={}".format(rQRiS8l30xE&t=627s)])

v_link = re.split("https://", str(link))

a_link = "https://"+v_link[2][:-3]

v_link = "https://"+v_link[1][:-2]

return_code = subprocess.call(["ffmpeg", "-loglevel", "verbose", "-ss", str(start), "-i", v_link, "-ss", str(start), "-i", a_link, "-t", "1:10", "-map", "0:v", "-map", "1:a", "-c:v", "libx264", "-c:a", "aac", download_path])
```

Could you please suggest why it works in the terminal but not within a python script.

Comment: Have you tried running the exact same commands in the terminal and then in your Python script?

Comment: I dont' know which subprocess call isn't working for you, but run `shlex.join()` instead of `subprocess.call()` and post its output.

Comment: Also, make sure that you are using the same ffmpeg executable

Comment: In your Terminal, run `which youtube-dl` and then use the full path in your `subprocess()` call.

Comment: According the [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68172718/ffmpeg-convert-to-h264-decoder-codec-av1-not-found-for-input-stream-00), it looks like the FFmpeg version is too old. It could be that the FFmpeg from python is not the same version as the FFmpeg from the from terminal. (more likely in Windows OS).

Comment: @Rotem ffmpeg version is same as I am using the same anaconda environment to run the commands from terminal and python script

Comment: Why are you hiding the URLs? Can you please edit you post, and add the actual `"URL"`, and `"1st-URL"` and `"2nd-URL"` and `video_id`, and the value of `v_link` and `a_link` and `start`. Please edit your post, and make sure we can execute the terminal commands and the Python code (add import statements, and missing values). What is the version of FFmpeg? What OS are you using?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 and ffmpeg -version gives me this (9c33b2f). I ended up writing a bash script instead of python as I could not figure out the problem.